# Turtlebot_navigation issue:local_map drifts after a long-distance movement

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot-navigation, amcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to upload some pictures to show my problem, but I don't have enough points. Therefore, I can only explain it with my poor English. Sorry.
I am using a turtlebot2 to do my experiments. It worked well for a long time. But this Monday, after I built a new map or maybe after I decrease the max_vel_x, I found it can not locate itself well any more.
I usually start my turtlebot2 at the same position as the position that I start to gmapping. At first, the local_map can match the static map well. But if I send a goal that is a long-distance away, the local_map would drift. Then the local_map can not match the static map well with not only distance but also orientation. I have tried everthing I can think out to fix it, but none of them worked.
Need help~~

The map is a big rectangle, about 6m*6m.
I can upload now.
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286623/turtlebot_navigation-issue:local_map-drifts-after-a-long-distance-movement./) by [LucYang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32184/lucyang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-26**:
It looks like your sensor can't see the walls all the way around. Have you recently increased the size of your map?

**Comment by [LucYang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32184/lucyang/) on 2018-03-26**:
No,the map is the same as it was at last week and it worked well. This problem appeared just yesterday.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-26**:
Can you repost the images as *screenshots* instead of pictures taken with a phone/camera?

**Comment by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on 2018-03-28**:
what if you set the goal  near your turtlebot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]
I did this and the turtlebot2 behaved better, but still not good enough.

---

Originally posted by [LucYang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32184/lucyang/) with karma: 56 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-28**:
Please don't use an answer to provide more information about your question. This isn't a forum. Please update your question with this information instead.